# magento 2 redirect url with parameters from controller

Tags: url, redirect, admin-controller, parameter

I am trying to redirect to a different controller from one controller . I also want to set an Url parameter along with the redirect. But this is throwing me an error

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect\Interceptor::setParam()

Here is my code.

```
public function execute()
{

    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/index/new');
    $resultRedirect->setParam('myname', 'Nuno Sousa');
    return $resultRedirect;
}
```

What is wrong with the above code? or is there any other way?

Comment: What will be your result url?

Comment: it will go to create new customer page

Comment: customer/index/new This is your custom page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass param like this :

```
$params = array('myname' => 'Nuno Sousa');
$resultRedirect->setPath('customer/index/new', ['params' => $params]);
```

You can retrive using this :

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Comment: @RohanHapani, how to link to controller from phtml with params?

Answer (score 7):

I am using Magento 2.3.4

```
$params = array('myname' => 'Nuno Sousa');
```

Somehow this did not work for me.

```
$resultRedirect->setPath('[modulename]/[controllername]/[actionname]', ['params' => $params]);
```

This worked.

```
$resultRedirect->setPath('[modulename]/[controllername]/[actionname]', $params);
```

Just in case if anyone having this same issue

Comment: I experienced the same thing in 2.3.4.

Comment: This should be the right solution in recent versions instead. it works in 2.4 too